# Network disruption when notebook attached to ethernet is suspended

Tags: fritzbox, synology-diskstation

I have been having this issue for a couple of months now where, if I suspend my notebook, while it is attached to the router via Ethernet, the entire network basically stops working (wired and wireless).

The notebook is attached to the router either directly via an Ethernet cable, or through a docking station, and in both cases the network stops working. Whipping out my trusty wireshark on another computer, I can see a lot of ARP requests that seem to go unanswered since the same hosts issue queries over and over again. Most of the queries are going from/to the configured gateway IP (192.168.0.1, a.k.a. the router) which is not surprising, but could be an indication. The router is an AVM Fritzbox 4040. The queries originating from the router are looking for the former notebook IP, while the queries to find the router are from a Synology NAS attached directly to the router (and the return address is 169.254.x.x which seems wrong to me).

Unplugging or resuming the notebook resolves this issue.

It's not a big problem, given that the temporary fix is rather simple, but I'd like to understand what is going on.

Comment: wild, unsubstantiated idea - the laptop won the election to be master browser & devices are wondering where it went. used to be an issue in our network here, solved by setting one of the always-on devices to be permanent master.

Comment: Not quite sure I follow what you mean. The only thing I can find for "master browser" are Windows domain specific things, which shouldn't be the case since this is a Linux-only network and the Notebook doesn't have any Samba server running, just the smbclient tools.

Comment: I'd assumed Windows. You'd assumed we'd assume nix. 169.254 is a self-assigned, non-routable address. Something is looking for its DHCP server & not finding it.

Comment: That is what I'd thought as well, but the DHCP server is actually sitting right next to the others on another ethernet port, and reachable, so it should be able to receive an IP. It's also strange that the Synology device which sends requests with the 169.254 address seems to immediately forget its IP as soon as the notebook suspends, which it shouldn't as long as I don't unplug its ethernet port which'd trigger a new assignment.

Comment: Is your DHCP server separate to your router/gateway? maybe there's a fight going on as to who's in charge. (I'm really doing nothing but guessing here, as you may be able to tell;)

Comment: No problem, I'm down to guessing as well :-) I have a pihole that has had its DHCP server disabled, and the router is in charge of assigning addresses. One thing that I wonder is whether it's on the physical layer, and there is a charge being applied to the port, that causes the other ports to fluctuate triggering an apparent disconnect on the NAS and other Ethernet connected devices.